# Following Slack bot tut using Node.js, no output on run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

Following a tutorial to run a simple Slack bot using node.js. Tutorial is here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-slack-bot-with-node-js-and-chuck-norris-super-powers

When running `node bin\bot.js` in the terminal, the cursor goes to a new line but does not print anything and continues to blink without any output.

Should I be expecting a stack trace or something? I'm not sure how to debug whats going on without any output. Heres the code:

lib/cookiebot.js:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var SQLite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var Bot = require('slackbots');

var CookieBot = function Constructor(settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
    this.settings.name = this.settings.name || 'cookiebot';
  //  this.dbPath = settings.dbPath || path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'data', 'cookiebot.db');

    this.user = null;
  //  this.db = null;
};

// inherits methods and properties from the Bot constructor
util.inherits(CookieBot, Bot);

module.exports = CookieBot;

CookieBot.prototype.run = function () {
    CookieBot.super_.call(this, this.settings);

    this.on('start', this._onStart);
    this.on('message', this._onMessage);
};


CookieBot.prototype._onStart = function () {
    this._loadBotUser();
  //  this._connectDb();
    this._firstRunCheck();
};

CookieBot.prototype._loadBotUser = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.user = this.users.filter(function (user) {
        return user.name === self.name;
    })[0];
};

CookieBot.prototype._connectDb = function () {
    // if (!fs.existsSync(this.dbPath)) {
    //     console.error('Database path ' + '"' + this.dbPath + '" does not exists or it\'s not readable.');
    //     process.exit(1);
    // }
    //
    // this.db = new SQLite.Database(this.dbPath);
};

CookieBot.prototype._firstRunCheck = function () {
    // var self = this;
    // self.db.get('SELECT val FROM info WHERE name = "lastrun" LIMIT 1', function (err, record) {
    //     if (err) {
    //         return console.error('DATABASE ERROR:', err);
    //     }
    //
    //     var currentTime = (new Date()).toJSON();
    //
    //     // this is a first run
    //     if (!record) {
    //         self._welcomeMessage();
    //         return self.db.run('INSERT INTO info(name, val) VALUES("lastrun", ?)', currentTime);
    //     }
    //
    //     // updates with new last running time
    //     self.db.run('UPDATE info SET val = ? WHERE name = "lastrun"', currentTime);
    // });
};

CookieBot.prototype._welcomeMessage = function () {
    this.postMessageToChannel(this.channels[0].name, 'Hi guys, roundhouse-kick anyone?' +
        '\n I can tell jokes, but very honest ones. Just say `Chuck Norris` or `' + this.name + '` to invoke me!',
        {as_user: true});
};

CookieBot.prototype._onMessage = function (message) {
    if (this._isChatMessage(message) &&
        this._isChannelConversation(message) &&
        !this._isFromCookieBot(message) &&
        this._isMentioningCookies(message)
    ) {
        this._replyWithRandomJoke(message);
    }
};

CookieBot.prototype._isChatMessage = function (message) {
    return message.type === 'message' && Boolean(message.text);
};

CookieBot.prototype._isChannelConversation = function (message) {
    return typeof message.channel === 'string' &&
        message.channel[0] === 'C';
};

CookieBot.prototype._isFromNorrisBot = function (message) {
    return message.user === this.user.id;
};

CookieBot.prototype._isMentioningCookies = function (message) {
    return message.text.toLowerCase().indexOf('cookies') > -1 ||
        message.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.name) > -1;
};

CookieBot.prototype._replyWithRandomJoke = function (originalMessage) {
    // var self = this;
    // self.db.get('SELECT id, joke FROM jokes ORDER BY used ASC, RANDOM() LIMIT 1', function (err, record) {
    //     if (err) {
    //         return console.error('DATABASE ERROR:', err);
    //     }
    //
    //     var channel = self._getChannelById(originalMessage.channel);
    //     self.postMessageToChannel(channel.name, record.joke, {as_user: true});
    //     self.db.run('UPDATE jokes SET used = used + 1 WHERE id = ?', record.id);
    // });
};

CookieBot.prototype._getChannelById = function (channelId) {
    return this.channels.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id === channelId;
    })[0];
};
```

bin\bot.js

```
'use strict';

var CookieBot = require('../lib/cookiebot');

var token = 'xxxxxx';
//var dbPath = process.env.BOT_DB_PATH;
var name = 'cookiebot';

var cookiebot = new CookieBot({
    token: token,
    name: name
  //  dbPath: dbPath,

});

cookiebot.run();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cookiebot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/cookiebot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/bot.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "main": "lib/cookiebot.js",
  "bin": {
    "cookiebot": "bin/bot.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "slackbots": "^0.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what your `CookieBot` is inheriting from the library but, there is nothing in your code that would print anything to the terminal.

The scotch.io tutorial says:

> If everything went fine you will see your NorrisBot appear in your Slack channel and a greeting message will be posted there. Try to invoke him by name several times and enjoy his jokes!

If you want to check whether it's working, check the slack channel it's connected to. Alternatively, add a few `console.log()` lines in there to get a feeling for how the code is running.

```
    CookieBot.prototype.run = function () {
      console.log( "Initialising Cookie Bot..." );
      CookieBot.super_.call(this, this.settings);

      this.on('start', this._onStart);
      this.on('message', this._onMessage);
    };

  CookieBot.prototype._onMessage = function (message) {
    console.log( "Cookie Bot received message..." );
    ...


    CookieBot.prototype._onStart = function () {
      console.log( "Cookie Bot started..." );
      ...
```